# Accessing class methods defined in a macro (c++)

Tags: c++, class, macros

I'm using a library in a project and there is a macro that is defined like this

```
#define Predicate4(P, t1, v1, t2, v2, t3, v3, t4, v4)                 
  class P : public Predicate {                                   
    t1 v1; t2 v2; t3 v3; t4 v4;                                       
    int sign ();                                                      
  public:                                                             
  P (t1 v1, t2 v2, t3 v3, t4 v4) : v1(v1), v2(v2), v3(v3), v4(v4) {}  
     Objects getObjects () { return Objects(v1, v2, v3, v4); } 
  };

Predicate4(Orient3D, Point *, a, Point *, b, Point *, c, Point *,d);

int Orient3D::sign ()
{
    PV3 u = d->getP() - a->getP(), v = b->getP() - a->getP(), 
        w = c->getP() - a->getP();
    return u.tripleProduct(v, w).sign();
}
```

So the Predicate takes a set of points and performs some operations. I need to access the orient3D.sign function(). How I do I pass the points and check the operation using the given method?

Comment: Point a, b, c, d; Orient3D object(&a,&b,&c,&d); then object.sign() does not work?

Comment: That worked. I wasn't familiar with this kind of class declaration. Thanks  :)